# js innerHTML displacement

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to load my data using js

i have created a function

```
function loadIFmulti() {
    var area= document.getElementById("multi");
    area.innerHTML="<table>";
    for(var i =0;i<multiLink.length;i++)
    {
        if(multiLink[i][0]==ques[current][2])
        {   
            for(var j=1;j<multiLink[i].length;j++)
            {
                for(var x=0;x<multiques.length;x++)
                {
                    if(multiques[i][j]==multiques[x][2])
                    { 
                        if(multiques[x][1]=="number")
                        {
                            area.innerHTML +="<tr><td>"+multiques[x][0] +"</td><td><input type=\"number\" class=nummulti></td></tr>";
                         }
                         else if(multiques[x][1]=="text")
                         {

                          }
                          else if(multiques[x][1]=="listoption")
                          {

                          }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    area.innerHTML += "</table>";
}
```

my data

```
 var multiques=[
                        ["logic","number","36",""],
                        ["text","text","35",""],
                        ["number","number","37",""]
        ];
```

the result is disappointed

```
<div id="multi"><table></table>logic<input type="number" class="nummulti"></div>
```

`table` closed before the loop finished,  `tr` and `td` doesn't printed so there's something very weird, hope anybody can help me

Comment: Please create a simplified working example to demonstrate your issue, currently there are lots of unknown variables in your js

Comment: Please add what you expect the output to be.

Comment: Not what you're asking but I suggest you try `document.createElement()` with `appendChild()` instead of generating a string.

Comment: @Walk - Isn't string concatenation faster though?

Comment: @Zera it is faster but `createElement` has many more advantages besides speed. I wouldn't use it for dynamic content personally.

Comment: adding to innerHTML is not like building a string! When you add a tag, it will close. Build a string and add it to the innerHTML at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `.innerHTML` as some sort of a consistent string variable, but it's a setter for the HTML markup (see DOM).

That means every time `innerHTML` is set, the html string will be parsed, even if tags aren't closed. That's causing your errors. You should never use `innerHTML` like that.

If you don't want to use `document.createElement()` and `Element#appendChild()`, you need to generate the html string independent with its own variable and then set the `innerHTML` to that string, so it can be parsed.

That should fix it:

```js
function loadIFmulti() {
    var html="<table>";
    for(var i =0;i<multiLink.length;i++)
    {
        if(multiLink[i][0]==ques[current][2])
        {   
            for(var j=1;j<multiLink[i].length;j++)
            {
                for(var x=0;x<multiques.length;x++)
                {
                    if(multiques[i][j]==multiques[x][2])
                    { 
                        if(multiques[x][1]=="number")
                        {
                            html +="<tr><td>"+multiques[x][0] +"</td><td><input type=\"number\" class=nummulti></td></tr>";
                         }
                         else if(multiques[x][1]=="text")
                         {

                          }
                          else if(multiques[x][1]=="listoption")
                          {

                          }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    html += "</table>";
    var area = document.getElementById("multi");
    area.innerHTML = html;

}
```